# How to implement export values in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I tried to create a simple example in AWS environments. In the beginning, I export 2 values:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= something
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= something
```

After that, I wrote a simple code.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  access_key = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  secret_key = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami = "ami-40d28157"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "terraform-example"
  }
}
```

When I define values instead of parameters **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID** and **AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY** everything  works OK, but with the provided code, I see the following error

```
on main.tf line 4, in provider "aws":
   4:   secret_key = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
access, specifying the resource name.
```

Some ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to define variables for the two keys and specify the variable values when running e.g. `terraform apply`

Comment: Note that the provider `aws` actually internally respects these (and other) environment variables, that is nothing you would need to do manually in this specific case of passing the aws environment credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. As explained in the `terraform` [authentication](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#authentication) documentation for AWS provider, `terraform` will automatically use the credentials in that order:

- Static credentials
- Environment variables
- Shared credentials/configuration file
- CodeBuild, ECS, and EKS Roles
- EC2 Instance Metadata Service (IMDS and IMDSv2)

So once you export your keys (make sure to export them correctly):

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="something"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="something"
```

in your config file you would just use (exemplified in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#environment-variables)):

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami = "ami-40d28157"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "terraform-example"
  }
}
```